# Exists $x_0 \in \partial M$ such that $\omega(x_0) \neq 0$.

Tags: analysis, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

Let M a compact manifold $C^k$ with boundary and orientable such that $\partial M \neq 0$ and $\omega \in \Lambda^{dim M -1}$ such that $d\omega (x) \neq 0, \forall x \in M$. Show that exists $x_0 \in \partial M$ such that $\omega(x_0) \neq 0$.

Hint: Start with $\overline{B(0,1)}$.

It's a homework problem.

My first idea was: $dω(x)≠0$, then exists an open set U such that $dω(U)≠0$. Let's say that $dω(U)>0⇒∫Udω>0$. Then use the Stokes theorem to conclude something like $∫_Vω>0$ and $ω(x0)≠0$ for some $x_0$.

Comment: What have you tried? It is exam season so you have to convince us this is not an exam question.

Comment: My first idea was: 
$d \omega (x) \neq 0$, then exists an open set U such that $d \omega (U) \neq 0$. Let's say that $d \omega (U) > 0 \Rightarrow \int_U d \omega > 0$. Then use the Stokes theorem to conclude something like $\int_V \omega > 0$ and $\omega (x_0) \neq 0$ for some $x_0$.

Comment: Try to make your argument global on $M$, not local on an open set.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thaks. :D

Comment: @LeandroC.Araújo Would you mind adding this attempt to the body of your question? That way it's less likely to get closed for lack of context. If you could include where you found it as well (so that we're not helping you cheat on an exam), that would be great.